# AJAX en la misma página

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

He estado probando AJAX mandandole la petición a la misma página que contiene el código AJAX, y funciona, el problema está en que además de la respuesta en concreta que quiero obtener, hay más código PHP, que por desgracia se muestra junto a la respuesta deseada. (Es decir, en el DIV, me trae todo el fichero .php y necesito una parte en concreto)

No quisiera tener que hacer un file.php para cada respuesta que quiero obtener, así que me preguntaba si existe alguna función o alguna forma de recoger unicamente lo que quisiera obtener.

Edito:

Subo el código completo a GitHub ya que no me deja postearlo aqui sin que se destroze la mitad.

[Link](https://github.com/SharkiPy/Code-stackoverflow/blob/master/Javascript.php)

Comment: Podrías por favor, incluir en tu pregunta ([editándola](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/163786/edit)) el código que has hecho para poderte ayudar a ajustarlo?

Comment: @Alfabravo Hola, acabo de editarlo como me pedías, espero haber sido esta vez algo más claro, gracias! :)

Comment: Hombre prueba incluir el nav  solo si no se detecta la llamada post, es decir colocale un else  a tu condición y es allí donde iría tu nav, de esa manera solo se imprime al acceder a la pagina y no con tus peticiones ajax

Comment: yo tuve un problema similar, en mi caso lo solucione asi, creando un array $data = new aray( 'error' => false, 'mens' => 'Confirmado', 'estado' => 1); return json_encode($data); y desde el ajax al recibir esos valores ya lo procesaba de la forma que necesitaba, asi me aseguraba de solo recibir lo que necesitaba y cosas de mas.

Comment: @CarlosQuintero Por algún motivo que se me está escapando, aunque el menú ahora no lo inserta, vuelve a insertar el formulario. He editado el código con el completo, sinceramente no veo el error.

Comment: Bueno bro, en realidad tu problema es que ajax va a capturar cualquier impresión en tu web, por ende también va capturar el formulario, lo que realmente te recomiendo es que crees un archivo externo para la tarea que buscas lo que en realidad va con las buenas prácticas

Comment: Lo siento, pero debes incluir en la pregunta el codigo relevante. si no, mira [mcve]

Comment: No creo que lo más conveniente sea enviar la petición Ajax al mismo archivo dónde se encuentra el formulario. Si quieres evitar el crear un archivo por cada petición la solución es muy fácil: **creas un solo archivo** que se encargará de gestionar **todas las peticiones**. Para diferenciarlas, agregas una clave particular a cada una en el `data` que posteas y usas `isset` en el archivo para operar según esa clave esté en los datos posteados... `if (isset($_POST["borrar"])){//código para borrar}`. Y así vas poniendo `isset` por cada operación.

Comment: @SharkiAragon, A. Cedano tiene razón, podrías hacer una copia de tu archivo original y llamarla en lugar de la misma pagina